# hybrid mobile app development features

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing one mobile app, the requirement is as follows.

```
 1.The app should work offline and online.
 2.It should have database in both local device and in the server.
 3.When internet is on data has to be synced between local and server. 
 4.At any point of time local data and server data should be the same.
```

I have done lot of research on this but not able to find whether hybrid app development supports or not. Some one says we can do but other link says it's difficult and might not be possible.

Please help to me sort out this issue.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

for sure it is possible to have those features in an hybrid app. All depend what you choose to use to deal with that or how you choose to program it.

Remember than an hybrid app have almost all features that a web application could have as it could use almost all technologies, tricks, frameworks and libraries out there.

I have already developed an hybrid mobile app using cordova, jquery and jquery mobile that meet points 1 to 3. Though I am not saying you need to use jquery, or any of the other tools. I described the solutions I use for that app, however they are maybe not the best but it was the most practical and easiest solutions given the time frame and budget.

1. Was achieved by mirroring the server "data base" the first time the app is installed with WiFi access. When no internet is available the the app use the local data, when it is available then it take the data from the server and update the local data.
2. The local database was not a formal one, just JSON data files, very similar to the ones provided by the web service.
3. You can be checking for an active internet connection with the cordova network functions, once detected try to reach the server to check if the actual connection is working, on success then proceed to request mirroring the data. Just be sure to check if the local data is newer to the server one and instead of overriding you should first update the changes in the server.
4. I think this point is a bit difficult given the fact that you want to work offline. When you are offline you couldn´t do too much to reflect the server data into the app, as you are offline. Then having an exact mirror at any time is not feasible. However having a mirror when you have connection then that is another story.

Having a perfect data sync should be done carefully and instead of programming you own solution try to use a service or tools for that, like http://www.couchbase.com/mobile.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hybrid applications are, at core, websites packaged into a native wrapper. They look and feel like a native app. Hybrid app have main features are portability (one code base, multiple platforms), Access to various hardware/software capabilties, cheaper orginigation costs, faster speed to market.